# I am only able to show this upper bound for $|x|<1$. But how to show it for all $x$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, power-series

EDIT: I think that I have now solved it, but I have *three* constants $C_{\alpha}$, one for the case |x|<1 (the easiest case), one constant for the case $|x|\ge 1$ but summing the series only from 0 to M-1, and one constant for the case $|x|\ge 1$ but summing the series from M to infinity.  Should I now take the **max** of all three constants...or *add* them?  Or perhaps just keep all three and the split into cases is fine?  But I am guessing that I need *one* $C_{\alpha}$ that works for all x.  What do you think?  Thanks,

I am looking at the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n \alpha} \sin\frac{x}{2^n} $$

and for any given $\alpha \in (0,1)$, I want to show that

$$\left|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n \alpha} \sin\frac{x}{2^n}\right|\le C_{\alpha}|x|^{\alpha}$$

for all $x \in\Bbb R $, and where $C_{\alpha}$ is a constant that may depend on $\alpha$.

I am able to show the upper bound only for $|x|<1$, using geometric series and the fact that $|\sin(x)| \le |x|$.

So I am looking for some help in showing the upper bound for the case $|x|\ge 1$.

The hint given in the problem for $|x| \ge 1$ is this:

Let $M$ be the integer with $2^M \ge |x| \ge \frac{1}{2}2^M$ and estimate the sum over $n<M$ and $n\ge M$ in different ways.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Further hint: one way is $|\sin(x)| \le |x|$.  The other is $|\sin(x)| \le 1$.

Comment: Thanks so much Professor Israel.  I think that I have now solved it, but I have *three* constants $C_{\alpha}$, one for the case |x|<1 (the easiest case), one constant for the case $|x|\ge 1$ but summing the series only from 0 to M, and one constant for the case $|x|\ge 1$ but summing the series from M to infinity.  Should I now take the **max** of all three constants...or *add* them?  Or perhaps just keep all three and the split into cases is fine?  I am guessing that I need *one* $C_{\alpha}$ that works for all x.  What do you think?  Thanks, @RobertIsrael,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the best thing to do in this situation is to let $C$ be the max of the $C_\alpha$, the sum of the $C_\alpha$, or some other easily obtainable number that you can show quickly is bigger than $C_\alpha\forall\alpha$. You do need one constant that works for all $x$, and actually showing one is important because there are sometimes situations where it looks like there is a bound, but you can't reconsile all of them. Consider the obviously unbounded $f(x)$. On every interval $[a,a+1]$, $f(x)<a+2$ yet the function is unbounded because you cannot combine those bounds into a single one that works for every $x$.

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks so much for your answer @StellaBiderman :-)